# Get ALL items in a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

it's very easy to get the number of items in a list, `len(list)`, but say I had a matrix like:
`[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]`
Is there a pythonic way to return 6? Or do I have to iterate.

Comment: use: `l = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` `sum(map(len, l))` to get the 6, but for you an item is a number, but an item for a list is just an item that can be another list, number, floating, object, etc.

Comment: The operation you're looking for is "flatten" the list. Then take the length of the flattened list

Comment: Probably iteration is the most readable solution IMO

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Comment: Whenever you're doing anything fancy with list, the answer is *always* "just use numpy".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
from itertools import chain
l = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
len(list(chain(*l))) # give you 6
```

the expression `list(chain(*l))` give you flat list: `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: Would this work if the Matrix was 3 dimensional as well ex `[[[1,2,3]]]`

Answer (score 1):

Make the matrix numpy array like this

```
mat = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
```

Make the array 1D like this

```
arr = mat.ravel()
```

Print length

```
print(len(arr))
```

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for the edit. I am now from a mobile device. I was unable to format the code from here.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]    
len([item for innerlist in l for item in innerlist])
```

gives you 6

Answer (score 0):

You just need to flatten list.
Numpy is the best option.
Still if you want, you can use simple `if/else` to flatten and return length of list.
Example,

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 'ID45785', False, '', 2.85, [1, 2, 'ID85639', True, 1.8], (e for e in range(589, 591))]




def to_flatten3(my_list, primitives=(bool, str, int, float)):
    flatten = []
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, primitives):
            flatten.append(item)
        else:
            flatten.extend(item)
    return len(flatten)
   
print(to_flatten3(list_1))
```

```
14

[Program finished]
```